# Use Quorum Plugin on another IDE; Sonic Pi; MIDI; javascript

Tags: javascript, plugins, ide, midi, eclipse-orion

I wrote a program that plays a song using sonic pi.  I have to transcribe the code to a web language (javascript).  Since I'm new at javascript I thought it would be ideal to use QUORUM (http://quorumlanguage.com/) to transcribe it since there is easy access to MIDI libraries, etc. (that I absolutely need).  I have a mac and tried to use netbeans, etc (all processes suggested on the quorum site) but they are not working.  So, I figured I should be able to use the Quorum plugin that I downloaded on another IDE (a cloud IDE would probably be better). I keep failing and I honestly don't know really know what I'm doing.  I'd prefer not to pay for an IDE.  I tried orion's cloud ide "che" but it won't let me download the plugin via the internet or give me an option for uploading or running a native file.

Basically, I would like to find someway I can use quorum on my Mac.

Please help.
Doing all this for my graduate degree.
Thanks.

Em.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use The Quorum Programming language, it MUST be in the Netbeans IDE. No exceptions.

The process of installing the plugin for Quorum Language Support is as follows:

1. MAKE SURE YOU HAVE THE LATEST VERSION OF THE JAVA DEVELOPMENT KIT!!! - This is VERY important as Quorum 3.0 uses the Latest Version of Java and Quorum compiles to Java Byte Code.
2. You MUST Have Netbeans 8.0 or greater (at most Netbeans 8.0.2). - This is also very important as Quorum 3.0 takes advantage of features in Netbeans 8.
3. Go to the plugins page. This can be done by clicking on "Tools" in the Menu Bar and then going to "Plugins"
4. Go to the Settings Tab and hit the button that says "Add"
5. In the Name Field, Type "Quorum"
6. In the URL Field, Type the following: http://quorumlanguage.com/updates/quorum/updates.xml
7. Now under "Available Plugins", Check the Box for Quorum
8. Click the Install Button
9. Restart Netbeans.

Now, upon completed load of the Netbeans IDE, The Quorum Module should ask you if you would like dictation of everything you do. If you do not want this, tell it that you do not. If you do, then go for it.

When you go to Create a new Project in Netbeans, you should see an option for Quorum. If you do see this,then you have successfully installed the Quorum Plugin to Netbeans.